# Is it possible for bash/readline to "clean up" completion suggestions out the terminal?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, readline

If you are using zsh and do a <kbd>tab</kbd> completion for commands, pathnames, options etc, whenever there are multiple potential matches the suggestions will be displayed below the prompt.
Once you chose a suggestion zsh will remove the list of suggestions out of the terminal, as you can see here:

[image]

[Image source](http://vysakh0.github.io/flying-start-with-zsh-shell/)

In contrast when bash offers completion suggestions it outputs the list and returns you to a new prompt.

[image]

[Image source](https://github.com/stecman/composer-bash-completion-plugin)
The zsh behaviour is preferable to me as the suggestions I never used offer no value and just produce more "noise" in the terminal.
Is it possible to configure bash/readline to behave like zsh in this way?

Comment: After skimming through the [Readline chapter of the Bash Reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html), I don't see any option to achieve this. Conceivably, there is a way with storing cursor position before completion and restoring screen after closing the complete-menu.

Answer (score 1):

short: it's possible but complex as `.inputrc` bindings.

long: As suggested in a comment, you *could* do something like this in your bash prompt and readline bindings.

Saving/restoring the cursor would be ineffective, since the only point at which you would be able to reliably clear the remainder of the screen would be on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to complete the selection.

Once you've passed control to `accept-line`, it is too late to clear the remainder of the screen.  It's possible (but complex) to define a series of real and ad hoc "key bindings" to make readline to do more than one operation.  See for example

- [Complex keybinding in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366450/complex-keybinding-in-bash)

But that approach limits you to sending characters to bash and issuing commands to readline.  None of the readline commands does

```
printf '\033[J'
```

to clear the *remainder* of the screen.  The closest would be readline's built-in `clear-screen` (**not** what you want).  Your binding would have to do something like

- `beginning-of-line`
- insert "`printf '\033[J';`"
- `end-of-line`
- `accept-line`

The `end-of-line` would work around a quirk of readline.  It allows you to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> *anywhere* on the line.  If your cursor were in the middle of the line, you'd have just a fragment of your input left visible (although bash would get the entire string).

Comment: interesting. so with readline you cant really make a call out into a wider collection of functions. you are limited to the predefined actions. So the fundamentally the reason zsh can do this is because you can register a widget with the line editor. then bind a key to call the widget then the widget gives you all the scripting capabilities of a shell (not just the line editor)

Comment: right - bash's extensibility here is limited to what you can do to the command before submitting it.